# eclipse won't run my exe file

Tags: c++, eclipse, mingw, exe

I'm trying to build and run my C++ program in eclipse but it won't work.  My program doesn't have a main function, but it does have WinMain and includes < windows.h >.  I compile it into an executable and everything works fine, but when I click "run" nothing happens.  When I drag the executable to my desktop and double click it it runs no problem.  But I would like to be able to run it directly from eclipse.

I've done some research and already tried the following:

I made sure "PE Windows Parser" is checked in "Binary Parsers."

I made sure the working directory is where the executable is (workspace/projectname/Release).

I made sure MinGW is in the PATH (I couldn't find msys, but everything is compiling fine so I don't think this is the problem).

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

1.- Go to Menu Run -> Run Configurations

2.- Double click over C/C++ Application in the left subwindow.

3.- At right subwindow, press button Search_Project and check your binary executable.

4.- Press Run.

If you need to pass arguments to your program, go to Arguments tab.

[image]

For next runs, you can use the PLAY toolbar button or use CTRL+F11.

[image]

Comment: I have already tried all those things.  Like I said in my post, when I press "run" nothing happens.  Eclipse acts as if it ran the program very quickly and then terminates it.  What _should_ happen is a window appears, but that never happens when I run the .exe through eclipse.

Comment: Do you need to use external dll's or dinamyc libraries to run your program? Are there in your system path?

Answer (score 0):

Change your compiler to Visual C++ instead of MinGW GCC. Just copy your code to separate files. Then, you simply create a new project using Visual C++ as your tool-chain. Then you simple paste the files into the directory, and then run it.