# Unable to run SDL program in Eclipse but able to do so in Windows Explorer

Tags: c++, eclipse, windows, runtime, sdl

I have installed and set up SDL and managed to get a tutorial example to build (the tutorial code is from http://zamma.co.uk/setup-sdl2-eclipse-windows/) as a C++ Project in Eclipse.

The problem is that when I try to run the application from Eclipse, the window doesn't appear, or perhaps it gets closed soon after appearing. Eclipse doesn't appear to show any errors.

When I open the folder containing the executable in Windows Explorer and double-click on the application, it works; a window appears with "Hello World" as the title and closes after two seconds.

How can I get the window to appear when I run from Eclipse? Any breakpoints I set are ignored by the debugger.

IDE: Eclipse Luna 4.4.1 
 OS:  Windows 7 64-bit

Comment: The programs working directory is usually different when running from an IDE, it's usually the project directory and not the folder where the executable is located. That might cause problems with paths and directories.

Comment: I tried placing a copy of the SDL2.dll file in the project directory but that didn't work. If I take it out of the Debug folder, which is where the executable is located, and then run the program from explorer, I get an error message stating that the DLL is missing. This message does not appear when I attempt to run it in Eclipse. Would editing the run/launch configurations work, and if so, what would I need to do?

Comment: "Any breakpoints I set are ignored by the debugger" - This will mostly likely be because you are using 'Run' instead of 'Debug'. Are you getting any messages in the console?

Comment: Also, are you sure you have set up your Run Configurations correctly? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15564977/eclipse-wont-run-my-exe-file

Comment: Just to clarify, when I tried setting breakpoints to step through the code I was using Debug, not Run.

Comment: In the CDT Global Build Console, it states the follow "Info: Nothing to build for HelloSDLExample".

Comment: I checked the above post, but it doesn't really solve my issue, I have set up the paths correctly and the linker settings. The run configuration is the same, is there something else I need to specify?

Comment: Does the program just exit straight away when run from Eclipse? If so then it is a most likely a problem with SDL initialization or window creation. The fact that the exe runs would suggest it is to do with the sdl.dll location. If the program runs. If the program does run and it is just no window being displayed then try placing some console output statements to debug where you code is getting to. Also place some error checking in i.e. check window isn't null after creating it.

Comment: I tried Debug again after restarting, this time it went to Debug mode. If I set breakpoints, I can see that a window is created but it's contents not cleared to white (appears to contain random contents of memory).

Comment: The window appears to run now in Eclipse (perhaps this was due to a Windows Update I recently had to complete, not sure), but the window doesn't display correctly. However when testing if the pointer is null using 
`if (!window) 
 {
     cout << "window handle is null";
 }
 else
 {
    cout << "window was successfully created";
 }`

It returns that the window was successfully created. Am I just misinterpreting the result of the code, ie is it working as it should?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The program now runs in Eclipse, so the solution may have been to refresh Eclipse and double check Build settings and Run configurations, as well as checking for any OS modifications that may affect the software running on it (thanks to all who replied for the help).