# Errors with SDL with correct code

Tags: c++, eclipse, sdl

this is no urgent question, but I was just wondering about a few things while getting in touch with SDL.

So, I started to read [this tutorial](https://open.gl/context) and implemented the following code snippet:

```
SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
SDL_Delay(2000);
SDL_Quit();
```

In the tutorial, it is said, that a console window should open and cloase after the 2 seconds. I am using eclipse and while running nothing happens. This seems to be a problem like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28480916/unable-to-run-sdl-program-in-eclipse-but-able-to-do-so-in-windows-explorer), but in contrast I am using Linux. And the other thing is, that I can run it from the console and it happens nothing too. After that, I read the [other tutorial](http://zamma.co.uk/setup-sdl2-eclipse-windows/) from the question and inserted the following lines to create a window:

```
SDL_Window *window = 0;
window = SDL_CreateWindow("Hello World!",
                          SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
                          SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
                          640, 480,
                          SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
```

This changed nothing regarding my problem, that no window is shown, but If I write the output of `SDL_Init()` to the console it returns '0' (success) while running from eclipse and '-1' (some error code) while running from the terminal. I started both with optirun (eclipse and in the terminal the final program).

After that, I just tried to implement the rest of the tutorial and created an OpenGL window with SDL and so on. I changed nothing else, but it works with eclipse and within the terminal and the window is shown, now.

Has anybody an idea why this works now and why there was the difference between eclipse and the terminal?

Comment: Instead of just voting down this question, please write a comment why this question should be bad. I can not change something, if I do not know what is wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by nothing happens? 
If you don't even get a console window when running program then you should probably request it, i.e. on VS it would be Linker->SubSystem->Console.

> And the other thing is, that I can run it from the console and it happens nothing too.

What did you expect to happen? Console window is already open, so the program should just do nothing for 2 seconds and exit.

> while running from eclipse and '-1' .. Has anybody an idea why this works now and why there was the difference between eclipse and the terminal?

Call SDL_GetError() and find out yourself! :)

```
if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) < 0) {
    printf("SDL_Init failed: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
}
```

Comment: I expect to hppen, that a console window opens and closes after a second. But it seams that I misinterpreted something written in the tutorial and that it does not open a new window and just shows the console application. And as I said, I am new to SDL and just looked at the documentation for SDL_init() for the error code, but there was nothing useful about the error code. And I just did not know that there is the function SDL_GetError(). But it is nice to know.

Comment: Exactly, the initial code snippet is there only to test if SDL functions are working. Actual window creation for SDL is covered a bit lower on the same page.

Comment: As I said, I used the code lines from above to create the window, but as I said too, this changed nothing and does not create a window. Now, I am using the same lines and it works. And the only different thing is, that I initialized the GL version before creating the window and created the window as an OpenGL window.

Comment: @DanceIgel are you sure the window is not created ? Did you check the result of [`SDL_CreateWindow`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_CreateWindow) and possible [`SDL_GetError`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetError) message when it failed ? As you aren't drawing anything you'll only see a frame (if your window manager draws one) blink on screen for 2 seconds.

Comment: @Leiaz Yes, I am sure that nothing happend. But it doesn't matter. Now, it works and that is enough.